# How to store an array of objects from server to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, socket.io

We need to store array of objects from server to client using ReactJS, but it does not work.

All of this is to display users connections in my client, but my user List state does not save anything.

Notes:

I am using these technologies:

- NodeJS (server)
- ReactJS (client)
- socket.io

[image]

Client code

```
const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);

  // get user connections data
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on(ALL_USERS, ({ users }) => {
      console.log(users);
      setUsersList(users);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log("LIST: " + usersList);
```

Server code

```
 const users = getUsers(socket.id);
 socket.emit(constants.ALL_USERS, {
        users: users,
 });
```

Comment: In what way is this failing?

Comment: when I write console.log(usersList), does not save anything, only appear Object [object]

Comment: Nowhere in the code shown are you doing that.  In what way is *the code you're showing us* failing?

Comment: Regarding the update... I would expect that `console.log` that's outside of `useEffect` to execute twice.  Once when the component first renders, and again when the component re-renders after the state is updated.  Between these two renders, does the value change at all?  Additionally, don't do this: `console.log("LIST: " + usersList);`  It tells you almost nothing about `usersList` because you're coercing it to be a string.  Instead, log the object itself: `console.log("LIST: ", usersList);`  When you do that, what specifically gets logged in both renders of the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't do this:

```
console.log("LIST: " + usersList);
```

This coerces `usersList` to be a string, which removes any useful information from objects/arrays.  Instead, log the object itself:

```
console.log("LIST: ", usersList);
```

Aside from that... Your screen shot from the console is pretty telling.  First, this is logged:

```
LIST:
```

Which implies that `usersList` contains nothing.  Then, after the state is updated and the component re-renders, this is logged:

```
LIST: [object Object]
```

Which implies that `usersList` now contains an object.  So despite your assertion that it "doesn't save anything" your debugging output clearly indicates that it *does* save something.  I suspect it's saving exactly what the server returns:

```
{
    users: users,
}
```

The server is successfully returning an object, and you're successfully storing that object in state.  The code is working, and your own tests indicate that.

---

You're *probably* getting confused on the difference between an array and an object which *contains* an array.  You're initially setting the state to an empty array:

```
const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);
```

But then in the `useEffect` operation you're setting it to the object returned from the server:

```
setUsersList(users);
```

Perhaps you meant to set it to just a property on that object?:

```
setUsersList(users.users);
```

Or, alterlatively, only return the array itself from the server:

```
socket.emit(constants.ALL_USERS, users);
```

Comment: fine, now I understand better what happened, thanks I appreciate you